# Django rest - PUT requires non-specified fields to have a default = Bug?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

### Goal:

I want to PUT a specific field to update an existing entry at id=22. I don't want to pass fields in my request that aren't getting updated.

```
{"color":"green"}
```

to the endpoint:

```
/api/apple/22
```

where the data is initially:

```
{
    "id": 22, 
    "color": "red", 
    "size": 4
}
```

### Problem:

Fields that don't have a default throw an error, e.g. `size`, saying "This field is required."

### Code:

**Model**

```
class Apples(TimeStampedModel):
    color = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    size = models.IntegerField()
```

**Serializer**

```
class AppleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Apple
        fields = '__all__'
```

**View**

```
class AppleView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Apple.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AppleSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
```

**Test**

```
def test_update_apple(self):
    url = reverse('apple-detail', kwargs={'pk': 22})
    data = {"color": "green"}
    admin = User.objects.get(username='admin')
    client = APIClient()
    client.force_authenticate(user=admin)
    response = client.put(url, data, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updatemodelmixin. You can override the partial_update method to achieve a "PATCH" like request.
I would try to do a HTTP patch in the test as the documentation suggests it and I guess you are trying to do a "Patch" and not a "Put".

Comment: That is helpful. Is it better practice to not override partial_update, but instead write `client.patch()` if my update is partial?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem, but pretty much expected behaviour. Django doesn't know what the field without a default value should be set to. Either give it a default value or set `blank=True, null=True` on it.

Comment: What is strange is that, once I do give the field a default value, Django is perfectly happy accepting the PUT with only {"color": "green"}, and doesn't reset the other fields to their defaults.